# chartjs 3.6.0 add X label

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I used following code in Chart 2.2.1 and it worked well and we can see label `Time`.
Now we want to upgrade to 3.6.0 due to security reasons, but snippet stopped working. I attach 2 fiddles
Working 2.2.1: https://jsfiddle.net/maksim_beliaev/2ru3g5ot/8/
Not working 3.6.0: https://jsfiddle.net/maksim_beliaev/q2poncyd/5/

How can I set label for X and Y axis with new chartjs? In online docs for Axis and Labels looks like that syntax should be correct

```
function create_line_chart(ctx, x_axis, version_1, y_axis_1, version_2, y_axis_2) {
    new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: x_axis,
            type: 'line',
            defaultFontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            datasets: [{
                label: version_1,
                data: y_axis_1,
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                borderColor: 'rgba(220,53,69,0.75)',
                borderWidth: 3,
                pointStyle: 'circle',
                pointRadius: 5,
                pointBorderColor: 'transparent',
                pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(220,53,69,0.75)',
            }, {
                label: version_2,
                data: y_axis_2,
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                borderColor: 'rgba(40,167,69,0.75)',
                borderWidth: 3,
                pointStyle: 'circle',
                pointRadius: 5,
                pointBorderColor: 'transparent',
                pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(40,167,69,0.75)',
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,

            tooltips: {
                mode: 'index',
                titleFontSize: 12,
                titleFontColor: '#000',
                bodyFontColor: '#000',
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                titleFontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                bodyFontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                cornerRadius: 3,
                intersect: false,
            },
            legend: {
                display: false,
                labels: {
                    usePointStyle: true,
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                },
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false,
                        drawBorder: false
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Time'
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false,
                        drawBorder: false
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Value'
                    }
                }]
            },
            title: {
                display: false,
                text: 'Normal Legend'
            }
        }
    });
}

var ctx = document.getElementById( "canvas" );
            ctx.height = 150;
            create_line_chart(ctx,  [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016],
                194,
                [0, 30, 10, 120, 50, 63, 10],
                221,
                [0, 50, 40, 80, 40, 79, 120],
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chart.js v3 has lots of API changes from Chart.js v2, you should pass your title configuration like this:

```js
const titleConfig = {
    scales: {
        x: {
            display: true,
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Time",
                padding: { top: 20, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 },
            },
        },
        y: {
            display: true,
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Value",
                padding: { top: 30, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 },
            },
        },
    },
};
```

More information on how to use title configuration can be found on the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scale-options/titles.html).
Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vkghzxLc/15/

Comment: great, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Basicly your whole options object is wrong, there are some major breaking changes in chart.js v3. For all changes please read the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html).

For the scale label to show you need to configure it in `options.scales.x.title.text`, also the tooltip and legend need to be configured in the plugins namespace, tooltip has been made singular

Comment: thanks! Somehow overlooked it